# Best format for Cinelerra video editor

Tags: video, sound, video-editor

what is the best input format for Cinelerra? I have tried various combinations of video and audio formats, but none has worked so far. Advance thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cinelerra handles uncompressed and lightly compressed videos best.
DV from professional camcorders and mjpeg from some digital cameras, these are usually in the .avi container. Be careful with very long highly compressed videos.

Reading this document may be helpful;

http://www.billauer.co.il/cinelerra-video-edit-quickstart.html

see the heading; Input formats.

This section of the Cinelerra manual may also help;

http://cinelerra.org/docs/cinelerra_cv_manual_en.html#SEC69